# I am not able to insert values into temporary table in a postgres function

Tags: postgresql

I have created a temporary table in PostgreSQL

```
create temporary table tempTable(
val int
)
```

I have another table newTable which has the following data:

```
val
5
6
0
8
7
0
9
2 
0
```

But my function

```
create or replace function getval(
out valOut int
)
As $$
Begin
    insert into newTable values(5) returning inserted.val into tempTable             
values(inserted.val);
End; $$
language plpgsql;
```

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR:  "temptable" is not a known variable
>
> LINE 6: ...to newTable values(5) returning inserted.val into tempTable ...

Can you please help me with this.
Thanks.

Comment: The real question is: why do you think you need a temporary table. They are very rarely needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify a table name with `returning`.

In order to do that, you need to [chain two CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
with new_rows as (
  insert into newtable (val) values (5)
  returning *
)
insert into temptable (val)
select val
from new_rows;
```